# How to switch on Enum in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

I'm watching The Boring Flutter Development Show where in one of the episodes they're showing the implementation of Bloc.

Now there's this chunk of code that I thought would be better replace with Switch statement, you know, in case there appears more cases in the future:

```dart
_storiesTypeController.stream.listen((storiesType) {
       if (storiesType == StoriesType.newStories) {
         _getArticlesAndUpdate(_newIds);
       } else {
         _getArticlesAndUpdate(_topIds);
       }
     });
```

... so I tried to implement it but it gave me some error saying that

> Type 'Type' of the switch expression isn't assignable to the type 'Stories Type' of case expressions.

So I came up with this workaround:

```dart
final storyType = StoriesType.newStories;

_storiesTypeController.stream.listen((storyType) {
    switch (storyType) {
      case StoriesType.newStories: {
        _getArticlesAndUpdate(_newIds);
      }
        break;
      case StoriesType.topStories: {
        _getArticlesAndUpdate(_topIds);
      }
        break;
      default: {
        print('default');
      }
    }
  });
```

... and everything works fine but I wonder if there's another way to switch Enum and why it says the value of local variable storyType isn't used, when I use it in this line:

```
_storiesTypeController.stream.listen((storyType)
```

and I switch over it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a redundant variable that lives in the outer scope:

```dart
final storyType = StoriesType.newStories;
```

Since the callback for `_storiesTypeController.stream.listen` defines a new variable named `storyType`, the variable from the outer scope is not used.
You can simply drop the redundant line:

```dart
final storyType = StoriesType.newStories;
```

After you have removed it, there should not be any warnings.
Additionally, you do not need curly braces in a `switch`-statement. The adjusted code would look like this:

```dart
_storiesTypeController.stream.listen((storyType) {
    switch (storyType) {
      case StoriesType.newStories:
        _getArticlesAndUpdate(_newIds);
        break;
      case StoriesType.topStories:
        _getArticlesAndUpdate(_topIds);
        break;
      default:
        print('default');
    }
  });
```

You can find out more about `switch` and `case` in [Dart's language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#switch-and-case).

Answer (score 1):

Switching on enums is easy, for example:

```
enum ActivityType {
  running,
  climbing,
  hiking,
  cycling,
  ski
}

extension ActivityTypeNumber on ActivityType {
  int get number {
    switch (this) {
      case ActivityType.running:
        return 1;
      case ActivityType.climbing:
        return 2;
      case ActivityType.hiking:
        return 5;
      case ActivityType.cycling:
        return 7;
      case ActivityType.ski:
        return 10;
    }
  }
}
```

More on enums and how to use their enhanced version